# Case Statement using || (OR)

Tags: ruby, hash, case

The following code I am trying to use to assign an email alias via an api to our ticketing system.

```
@email.cc_list = case @site_id
  when /site1/ || /site2/; "smail-alias-1"
  when /site3/ || /site4/ || /site5/ || /site6/; "email-alias-2"
  when /site7/ || /site8/; "email-alias-3"
  when /site9/; "email-alias-4"
  when /site10/; "email-alias-5"
end
```

the problem is that only site 1, 3, 7, 9, and 10 are actually being assigned properly.  anything after the || isn't working.

I would rather avoid 10 when statements for 5 alias's.  Is there a way that I can make this case statement work with a hash in order to get the system to determine when it matches the specified site_id? or another way to make the or functions work?

Comment: why did you used `||`, you could list them using `,`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write :

```
@email.cc_list = case @site_id
                 when /site(1|2)/ then "smail-alias-1"
                 when /site(3|4|5|6)/ then "email-alias-2"
                 when /site(7|8)/ then "email-alias-3"
                 when /site9/ then "email-alias-4"
                 when /site10/ then "email-alias-5"
                 end
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't even think about using union.  For some reason my mind locked on or's.

Answer (score 2):

Not to give you the correct ways since others have done that, but will be good for your knowledge why your original code fails.

```
case @site_id
  when /site1/ || /site2/ ...
```

does not translate to:

```
if @site_id =~ /site1/ || @site_id =~ /site2/ ...
```

but to:

```
if @site_id =~ /site1/ || /site2/ ...
```

which is parsed as:

```
if ((@site_id =~ /site1/) || /site2/) ...
```

so, when the first match fails, it returns `nil`. `nil` ||-ed with a regex object has the value of regex object itself. A regex object in condition has boolean value of... you guess: `false`

you will even get a:

> warning: regex literal in condition

if you do it directly in an if statement.

Comment: Shouldn't  "which is parsed as" be `if @site_id =~ /site1/`, since the regex (itself) is truthy?

Comment: @CarySwoveland from what I read (only `nil` and `false` evaluates to false), yes, but apparently the interpreter (at least in Ruby 2.2.X) says no. regex object evaluates to `false` which easily proven by `puts "truthy" if /x/`. it's not that simple though, because if the regex is passed indirectly in condition, such as through method parameter, then it's indeed truthy. weird Ruby...

Answer (score 2):

You might prefer to write:

```
@email.cc_list = case @site_id[/\d+/].to_i
                 when 1,2  then "smail-alias-1"
                 when 3..6 then "email-alias-2"
                 when 7,8  then "email-alias-3"
                 when 9    then "email-alias-4"
                 when 10   then "email-alias-5"
                 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join your regexes w/ [Regexp.union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-union):

```
@email.cc_list = case @site_id
  when Regexp.union(/site1/, /site2/); "smail-alias-1"
  when Regexp.union(/site3/, /site4/, /site5/, /site6/); "email-alias-2"
  when Regexp.union(/site7/, /site8/); "email-alias-3"
  when /site9/; "email-alias-4"
  when /site10/; "email-alias-5"
end
```

Or make the regex like `/site1|site2/` yourself which is what union would basically do for you here.